# How to connect Sim800c development board to raspberry pi 3

Tags: pi-3b+, uart, gsm

i bought this development board Professional Small Size SIM800C GSM GPRS Module Quad-band Development Board Module Suitable for Raspberry Pi (blue & silver) https://www.amazon.it/dp/B07NVZ59JS/ref=cm_sw_r_awdo_navT_g_WGJMH8DZPJFTEGPA4Y0W
if I mount it directly on the raspberry pi 3 everything works correctly. my goal is to power it externally from the micro usb connector (5v 2A) and use only the tx and rx pins for communication: the development board turns on but if I connect to the raspberry only the tx and rx pins the communication does not work. do i have to connect some other pins too? thanks for support

Answer (score 0):

When communicating signals by a voltage between devices (e.g. a serial link) you need a common reference voltage (e.g. ground).

Connect a Pi ground pin to the other end's ground pin.

Comment: hi joan as you suggested I connected a GND pin from the raspberry to the pin with the yellow plastic of the development board (pin number 2 = gnd) and everything seems to work. I did this because if I connect the gnd pin of the raspberry to the corresponding pin of the board it doesn't work. One question: suppose the two devices are powered by the same power supply (5v 10a for example). Is it still necessary to connect a GND cable between the two devices? https://ibb.co/zNsys9n

Comment: Yes, you must connect the ground.